# How could I pick the string by gsub?

Tags: r, gsub

I have strings like this:

```
df
[1] "XID\t5647: asasaasa" "XID\t1540"
```

how could I pick only numbers after "XID\t" by using gsub?
I've used gsub as follows:

```
gsub(".*XID\t(.*)\\:.*", "\\1", df)
>[1] "5647"     "XID\t1540"
```

or

```
gsub(".*XID\t(.*)", "\\1", df)
>[1] "5647: asasaasa" "1540"
```

but I expect it like this:

```
[1] "5647" "1540"
```

I think cases are overlap, so I have to use gsub twice so that I could pick them like I want. Please give me your idea, thank you.

Comment: Do you have any patterns other than the numbers that follow `XID\t`

Answer (score 4):

We can use `str_extract` to match the numeric part (`\\d+`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df, "\\d+")
#[1] "5647" "1540"
```

Or with `gsub` to match all non-numeric (`\\D+`) and replace it with `""`.

```
gsub("\\D+", "", df)
#[1] "5647" "1540"
```

Or using the OP's syntax to match one or more numeric (`\\d+`) that follows the "XID\t", capture it as a group (`(...)`) and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`).

```
sub(".*XID\t(\\d+).*", "\\1", df)
#[1] "5647" "1540"
```

#### data

```
df <- c("XID\t5647: asasaasa", "XID\t1540" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace anything that is not a digit with ""

```
x=c("XID\t5647: asasaasa", "XID\t1540" )
gsub("[^0-9]","",x)
#[1] "5647" "1540"
```